# Trying to connect to SQL Server through SQL Server Management Studio for the first time won't connect

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-management-studio

Hey all so my problem is that I try to connect before even accessing the object explorer or anything and have ended up with this error. I've tried using Windows Authentication which is what I want to connect with normally. Any ideas of what I can do to fix this?

Here is the error details from the error log:

[image: Connection Error]

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.         Login failed for user
>   'mypcname\sql2012'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name
>   provided. [CLIENT: < local machine >]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you added the user?

Comment: It appears SSMS is attempting to use the local username on the machine.  If the SQL Server is not installed on the local machine, but instead on a remote machine, you will have to configure SSMS to use a user that both machines will know about.  The error is indicating you are attempting to authenticate as a user that SQL Server is unaware of.

Comment: @DavidPostill I cannot connect too add any users.

Comment: @Ramhound I am running the server on my local machine.

Comment: @Fuey500 - During the installation of MS SQL Server you were given a prompt to create a user with a password.  The standard administrator user should exist with a username of **sa**

Comment: [What is the default password for SQL Server 2012 if I didn't put a password in the setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217540/what-is-the-default-password-for-sql-server-2012-if-i-didnt-put-a-password-in-t)

Comment: It may be possible that you have SQL Management Studio installed but you have no running instance of SQL Server.  Can you look in the Services console (`services.msc`) and see if you can see the SQL Service running? You may have also unknowingly created a named instance, such as `server\instancename`

Comment: Thank you all for the help! so far I think I may have found the solution.